# adding space between icon and text in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a text field where i have added a text and icon. Like screenshot below:

[image]

However i want to have space between the icon and the text..

I tried this code:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
let image = UIImage(named: "username")
imageView.image = image
let viewLeft: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 20))
viewLeft.addSubview(imageView)
```

but got this:

[image]

how to add the space after the icon not before?

Comment: `UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))` => `UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))`?

Comment: Can you please add code of UiTextField as well in your question.

Comment: @Larme tried this also and nothing changed.. i got the same result in the first screenshot ...

Comment: @aBilal17 i have added it from the storyboard not from the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can try below code :-

```
public func setLeftView(of image: UIImage!) {

        //setting left image

        self.paddingLeft = 50
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        let paddingImage = UIImageView()
        paddingImage.image = image
        paddingImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        paddingImage.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: 23, height: 40)
        paddingView.addSubview(paddingImage)
        self.leftView = paddingView
        self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    }
```

Comment: thanks! worked as i want after some modifications! thanks alot :)